# importing networkx object to gephi - KeyError: <type 'numpy.int64'>

Tags: python, numpy, networkx, gephi

I don't know what broke my code, but when I try to export my network object into a gephi object, i keep getting key error numpy.int64. I'm iterating through the combnol list and placing the network object into the write_gexf function.

```
Combnol = 
[[1992, <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x10dfc5b50>],
 [2000, <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x10dc58650>],
```

This is what the network object looks like

```
combnol[1].edge
{'Alliances  Partnerships': {'Education': {'difference': 1.0,
   'weight': 1,
   'year': 2001},

combnol[1].node
{'Alliances  Partnerships': {'color': 'y'},
 'Education': {'color': 'y'},
 'Entrepreneurship': {'color': 'y'},

#save file 
for i, no in enumerate(combnol):
    print repr(no[1])
    nx.write_gexf(no[1], 'no{0}'.format(i))
    break
```

Traceback

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1536-80e0a534cec9> in <module>()
      2 for i, no in enumerate(combnol):
      3     print repr(no[1])
----> 4     nx.write_gexf(no[1], 'no')
      5     break

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gexf.pyc in write_gexf(G, path, encoding, prettyprint, version)

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/utils/decorators.pyc in _open_file(func, *args, **kwargs)
    261         # Finally, we call the original function, making sure to close the fobj.
    262         try:
--> 263             result = func(*new_args, **kwargs)
    264         finally:
    265             if close_fobj:

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gexf.pyc in write_gexf(G, path, encoding, prettyprint, version)
     75     writer = GEXFWriter(encoding=encoding,prettyprint=prettyprint,
     76                         version=version)
---> 77     writer.add_graph(G)
     78     writer.write(path)
     79 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gexf.pyc in add_graph(self, G)
    286         self.graph_element=graph_element
    287         self.add_nodes(G,graph_element)
--> 288         self.add_edges(G,graph_element)
    289         self.xml.append(graph_element)
    290 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gexf.pyc in add_edges(self, G, graph_element)
    361             edge_data=self.add_viz(edge_element,edge_data)
    362             edge_data=self.add_attributes("edge", edge_element,
--> 363                                           edge_data, default)
    364             edges_element.append(edge_element)
    365         graph_element.append(edges_element)

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gexf.pyc in add_attributes(self, node_or_edge, xml_obj, data, default)
    379             if k == 'key':
    380                 k='networkx_key'
--> 381             attr_id = self.get_attr_id(make_str(k), self.xml_type[type(v)],
    382                                        node_or_edge, default, mode)
    383             if type(v)==list:

KeyError: <type 'numpy.int64'>
```

UPDATE - in response to question:

```
print type(combnol[2][1].edge['Education']['Foundations']['difference'])
<type 'float'>
```

So is it simply am atter of making sure i add in ints, and not floats? 
    int(combnol[2][1].edge['Education']['Foundations']['difference'])

This is my current implementation where values are added. should I add an int() around the 1's below? g[pair[0]][pair[1]]['weight'] += int(1); int(1 / weight)

```
        # adjusting weight and difference if edge already exists
            #print pair[i][0], pair[i][1]
            if g.has_edge(pair[0], pair[1]):
                g[pair[0]][pair[1]]['weight'] += 1

            # adding edge if non-existant with initial weight = 1
            else:
                weight = 1
                g.add_edge(pair[0], pair[1], weight = weight, difference = 1. / weight, year= year)
```

Comment: What are the data types for the values in the edge? That particular code is trying to serialize the value, and it does by type. So, there's an entry in the dictionary for 'int', and that basically calls `str(int)`, but there apparently isn't one for numpy ints. Solution: Either convert to a 'normal' int when adding to the networkx edge, or add conversion for numpy ints into the networkx source.

Comment: updated to asnwer your question... let me try that

Comment: I don't see where you are using numpy.int64 types.  But you must be somewhere.  Use regular Python integers if you want to write graphml.

Comment: how do i use regular python integers? does that simply mean writing 1

Comment: @user3314418 - yeah, it's not an int vs. float thing. Are you using numpy at all? If not, then I don't understand why you are getting this error either. If you are, then yes, just do `int(numpy_int)` when adding to the graph.

Comment: Hm, can I point you to 'update 3'? I've posted my entire create network object function, and maybe I'm missing something? I odn't see where I'm using numpys...

Comment: Actually I got it figured out. I had an extra 'years' attribute that used numpy. thanks everyone!